# Resistor to limit maximum voltage of solar panels

Tags: motors, photovoltaics

I have two 20W solar panels (each Voc = 22.3, Isc = 1.22) in series connected directly to an axial fan driven by an EC motor (rated voltage 48V). Here the maximum operating voltage when very sunny has been about 43 V. This configuration has worked well in the past but I need a bit more airflow. I want to add in series another panel, this one is a 10W, same voltage, about half the current. I have read elsewhere that this not need to be a problem for the panels since the operating current will fall to that of the smallest panel. That is fine to me, at the moment I am not aiming for high efficiency. What worries me is that the EC motor might get too much voltage out of the three panels. From the panel curves it appears that with full sun (around 1000 W/m2) the motor might get 60-62 V. The operating voltage range of the fan according to its data sheet is 28-56 V. The rated current is 0.5 A, however when I connected the fan to 56V I measured 0.4 A. Is it possible to connect a power resistor in series in the circuit so that with full sun the motor "sees" about 56V instead of 60-62V? Is there a way to calculate the required resistance? Unfortunately for me the fan does not have much information on its properties to help with this.

I would appreciate some guidance with this. Thanks.

Comment: That is not what resistors are for.  That's what zeners are for, or better yet, voltage regulators.

Comment: Could you help me further? How can I apply a Zener diode here? I will now use three 10 W panels in series which give me a maximum voltage of about 60-62 by full sunny conditions. Since I am connecting the panels directly to the fan, the voltage and current vary during the day and between days. My objective is  simply to avoid that the fan is exposed to more than 56 V. Some easy and cheap way to limit the voltage to that value. But also that, when it is not so sunny and the panel gives for example 30 V, the fan still runs at its usual speed for that voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Get 6 volt panels that match the amps of the other panel and run them in series. 2 Get another match to the one you have to increase the amperage and run them parallel. Picture below is in series.

[image]